# Spelling on "Help Center > Asking"

Tags: bug, status-completed

On *[Help Center > Asking](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* there is:

> try StackOverflow ... administration - try ServerFault ... try WebApps

That should be:

> try Stack Overflow ... administration - try Server Fault ... try Web Applications

See *[Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)* (the last section) and [the about page for Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Good catch! I just changed it. Thank you for pointing that out.